# How to get hrefs referring to elements with distinct values using XSLT 2.0 or XPath 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML input

```
<a href="h1" />
<a href="h2" />
<a href="h3" />

<b id="h1">E1</b>
<b id="h2">E1</b>
<b id="h3">E2</b>
<b id="h4">E3</b>
<b id="h5">E3</b>
<b id="h6">E4</b>
<b id="h7">E5</b>
```

Is there a way using XSLT2/Xpath2 to get only h1 and h3 referring to the distinct values E1 and E2 and ignore h2 since it refers to the same value E1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**, assuming `a` and `b` are children of the top element:

```
   for $href in /*/a/@href,
       $b in /*/b[@id = $href and not(. = preceding-sibling::b)]
     return
       string($href)
```

**XSLT - 2 based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "for $href in /*/a/@href,
           $b in /*/b[@id = $href and not(. = preceding-sibling::b)]
          return
             string($href)
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<html>
    <a href="h1" />
    <a href="h2" />
    <a href="h3" />
    <b id="h1">E1</b>
    <b id="h2">E1</b>
    <b id="h3">E2</b>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
h1 h3
```

**Update**:

As fairly noted by Michael Kay, the above solution is O(N^2) and can be slow in case there are many `b` siblings.

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution that is at least linear (or faster):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kReferrer" match="b" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="key('kReferrer', a/@href)" group-by=".">
     <xsl:sequence select="string(@id)"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again, when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
h1 h3
```

Comment: But that's another quadratic solution - quite unnecessary, surely. But you seem to have understood the requirement differently from me since your solution involves looking at the `a` elements and mine doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I think both DevNull and I wanted to provide a pure XPath 2.0 solution and understood this question as an XPath challenge. As for your solution, I think you didn't quite understand the requirement -- only such `b` that are referenced from `a`s should be selected. So, it would be a little bit more complex.

Comment: Sorry to impose on you Dimitre, but I know you enjoy a good challenge :). Does this have a snowball's chance in hell of being answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624325

Comment: @Kev, What do you mean? THere *are* three good answers, and my answer with its latest update is both efficient and compact.

Comment: @Kev, As for the question in your commen's link -- it is  a good candidate for "Close" -- very long and not well-defined. Also, it seems that through the pushes of LarsH the OP found the cause of his problem and doesn't need an answer anymore.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - sorry I didn't mean anything on this thread, I just meant on the question I linked to.

Comment: @Kev, As I said, the question isn't challenging but rather confusing -- this is why LarsH didn't answer it but just by asking comments he was able to tell the OP what the cause is.

Comment: @Kev, I think that other question should be closed. The answer was simply that some required files hadn't been put in the necessary relative locations. I don't think that's going to be useful to anyone.

Comment: @LarsH and Dimitre - heh, it's late (02:00) I scanned the comments, but they didn't filter through. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @LarsH, Agree, although you spent a lot of effort helping the OP. If you manage to post an answer before the question is closed, I'd +1 with pleasure.

Comment: @LarsH, Thanks :) Congrats to you for exceeding 10K.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I live in a different timezone. Thanks a lot for all of you for the solution, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this XPath:

```
/*/b[@id = /*/a/@href and not(preceding::b = .)]
```

Comment: Ouch - using preceding axis in a predicate - that's quadratic performance in the size of the document. Quite unnecessary. Though admittedly we have no idea how big the document is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble seeing what role the `<a>` elements play - it seems to me the problem only involves the `b` elements - have I misunderstood it completely?

Given your input, with the parent of the given nodes as the context item,

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="b" group-by=".">
  <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/@id"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

will return h1 h2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My target is to get <a> elements referring to distinct <b> elements. The number of <a> elements are far less than <b>s, I edited my question to reflect this. Sorry for the not so complete question.